# routes.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I created a new workspace in Cloud9 to start from scratch called project3. I am following the rails-tutorial by **Michael Hartl**. I am trying to see my running application and I'm getting

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/candy_3_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `':
>   uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

My CandyPagesController looks like this:

```
class CandyPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def butterfinger
  end

  def reeses
  end

  def snickers
  end

  def skittles
  end

  def mandm
  end
end
```

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'candy_pages/home'

  get 'candy_pages/butterfinger'

  get 'candy_pages/reeses'

  get 'candy_pages/snickers'

  get 'candy_pages/skittles'

  get 'candy_pages/mandm'
```

candy_pages is on a branch of master.  I didn't want to commit it until I confirmed I could see it.

Comment: Hi TheChamp, I'm really green....do you have to install Rails for every project?  Do you know why when I did the generate the name didn't change to the project name?

Comment: Actually no, if you installed it on your system it should stay there. But did you install it on cloud 9?

Comment: `gem 'rails'` should be there in your `Gemfile` by default. You can add it in Gemfile and run `bundle install` if it's missing

Comment: It is installed in Cloud9.  And I did a rails install too.  This was my generate  ssouza8@project3:~/workspace/candy_3_app (candy-pages) $ rails generate controller CandyPages home butterfinger reeses snickers skittles mandm

Comment: Well it somehow doesn't find rails, which is strange if you say you already installed it

Comment: So `bundle install` worked without any errors?

Comment: yes   $ bundle install --without production....  Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.

Comment: Before I did the 'bundle install' I had installed rails 4.2.0...'Successfully installed rails-4.2.0'.  Should I change    **Rails.application.routes.draw do** to **candy_3_app.application.routes.draw do**

Comment: Is `end` missing at the end of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: nope...there is an end after a lot of comments from the rails-tutorial.  (how do you put a background color around code?)